# Update all records with same boolean if at least one record meets the criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering if they way I am trying to update a set of records is the best way or if there is a more efficient way to handle this.

Example Table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ListItems] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
    [EmailAddress] nvarchar(MAX)  NULL ,
    [FirstName] nvarchar(MAX) NULL ,
    [LastName] nvarchar(MAX)  NULL ,
    [IpAddress] nvarchar(MAX) NULL,
    [IsUnsubscribed] bit,
    [Md5Hash] varchar(250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ListId] int,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ListItems_dbo.Lists_ListId] FOREIGN KEY ([ListId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Lists] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    )


CREATE INDEX [IX_MD5] ON [dbo].[ListEmailItems]
([Md5Hash] ASC) 
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

User's can be part of multiple lists and there is a flag if they are unsubscribed from a specific list. There are times where a user wants to be removed from all lists. Their ID will be different for each list, so I cannot use the ID as an identifier. I have an index on the Md5Hash so I am using that since it is unique for each email address. This is what I setup so far in that case, but it is slow if there are a lot of records to look through:

```
Update ListItems set IsUnsubscribed = 1 where IsUnsubscribed = 0 and  Md5Hash in (Select Md5Hash from ListItems where IsUnsubscribed = 1)
```

I was curious if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: Why not fix your design, store the hash and subsrcibe status in a different place, where there is only one row per hash value? Then you don't have to worry about any of this redundant information needing to be updated all over your table...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, good idea, but not going to happen this iteration of our application. There is too much infrastructure in place with regards to this design.

Comment: FirstName = `NVARCHAR(MAXX)` why?

Comment: None of these columns should be NVARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: @zane, this question is not a critique of the table structure nor does it matter to what I am trying to achieve or answer my question!

Comment: @DDiVita or maybe it would be important and helpful to take the advice some of the experts on here are giving you instead of becoming defensive. This is volunteer time. You're not paying me so how about instead of just saying "Solve my problem for me!" you could take some of the constructive criticism and apply it to future builds. Since using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for any of this columns is a **bad** idea.

Comment: @zane, perhaps instead of asking "why" and  stating it is a bad idea, we stress why it is not desirable to use. Perhaps that is your opinion or opinion the of others. How would I know it is a bad idea otherwise? Maybe there is a reason for the type being used, but in this case it is not pertinent to my question. What's more, I did not ask anyone to "Solve my problem for me". I asked if what I was trying to do was the best way of achieving my goal or if there was a better way.

Comment: @DDiVita I'm sorry the quote was "answer my question!". I originally asked why you are doing that as there is no visible reason to do so and would be a waste of storage at best. All I did was ask you a question and you got defensive. Relax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is about as good as you're going to do, but I would probably re-write it as an `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE li
  SET IsUnsubscribed = 1
  FROM dbo.ListItems AS li -- always use schema prefix!
  WHERE IsUnsubscribed = 0
  AND EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ListItems
      WHERE Md5Hash = li.Md5Hash
      AND IsUnsubscribed = 1
  );
```

Of course another idea would be to check for the existence of at least one value of `1` at query time, instead of constantly having to run this query to keep all the values at `1`. This is busy work for no good reason.

I still think you can abstract this status away into another table (as [I suggested in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001249/update-all-records-with-same-boolean-if-at-least-one-record-meets-the-criteria?noredirect=1#comment31560882_21001249)) in a way that is transparent to the surrounding infrastructure. Views, synonyms, enforcing data access through stored procedures, etc. can all assist in this...

Comment: I agree that it should be designed differently, but like I sated, it is not going to happen right now and this is the best solution to our current infrastructure.